# how to change the colors of multiple subplots at once?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looping through a bunch of CSV files containing various measurements.

Each file might be from one of 4 different data sources.

In each file, I merge the data into monthly datasets, that I then plot in a 3x4 grid. After this plot has been saved, the loop moves on and does the same to the next file.

This part I got figured out, however I would like to add a visual clue to the plots, as to what data it is. As far as I understand it (and tried it)

```
plt.subplot(4,3,1)
plt.hist(Jan_Data,facecolor='Red')
plt.ylabel('value count')
plt.title('January')
```

does work, however this way, I would have to add the `facecolor='Red'` by hand to every 12 subplots. Looping through the plots wont work for this situation, since I want the `ylabel` only for the leftmost plots, and `xlabel`s for the bottom row.

Setting `facecolor` at the beginning in

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15),facecolor='Red')
```

does not work, since it only changes the background color of the 20 by 15 figure now, which subsequently gets ignored when I save it to a PNG, since it only gets set for screen output.

So is there just a simple `setthecolorofallbars='Red'` command for `plt.hist(…` or `plt.savefig(…` I am missing, or should I just copy n' paste it to all twelve months?

Comment: have you tried using `mpl.rc("axes", facecolor="red")`? I am not sure how your plot should look like in the end, so this is just a guess...

Comment: In this instance `facecolor` becomes a background color again, but I guess if I find that right switch, that could indeed be a workable solution! I will read around in the documentation for it.

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to color here, the histogram bars? In that case `mpl.rc("axes", color_cycle="red")` should work.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the matching command. Can you post it as an answer please, so that this question won't remain unanswered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mpl.rc("axes", color_cycle="red")` to set the default color cycle for all your axes.

In this little toy example, I use the `with mpl.rc_context` block to limit the effects of `mpl.rc` to just the block. This way you don't spoil the default parameters for your whole session.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

# create some toy data
n, m = 2, 2
data = []
for i in range(n*m):
    data.append(np.random.rand(30))

# and do the plotting
with mpl.rc_context():
    mpl.rc("axes", color_cycle="red")
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(n, m, figsize=(8,8))
    for ax, d in zip(axes.flat, data):
        ax.hist(d)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the x- and y-labels (when you use loops) can be solved by using `plt.subplots` as you can access every axis seperately.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random

# creating figure with 4 plots
fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,2)

# some data
data = numpy.random.randn(4,1000)

# some titles
title = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','April']

xlabel = ['xlabel1','xlabel2']
ylabel = ['ylabel1','ylabel2']

for i in range(ax.size):
    a = ax[i/2,i%2]
    a.hist(data[i],facecolor='r',bins=50)
    a.set_title(title[i])

# write the ylabels on all axis on the left hand side
for j in range(ax.shape[0]):
    ax[j,0].set_ylabel(ylabel[j])

# write the xlabels an all axis on the bottom
for j in range(ax.shape[1]):
    ax[-1,j].set_xlabel(xlabels[j])


fig.tight_layout()
```

All features (like titles) which are not constant can be put into arrays and placed at the appropriate axis.

Comment: This should work, but setting up three loops for 12 plots doesn't really make sense to me. Hence my question for a "global" way to set all colors.